# How to make an alias permanent?

Tags: command-line, bash

I create an alias behavior

```
alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"
chrome foo.html
```

Nevertheless, It refuses to work when I restart the terminal.

```
$ chrome foo.html
-bash: chrome: command not found
```

As a solution, I place the command to `~/.bash_profile`

```
# Add to ~/.bash_profile
# shortcut for chrome
alias chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'"
```

Again, it report similar error

```
$ chrome foo.html
-bash: chrome: command not found
```

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: Did you try adding it to `.bashrc`?

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`? Note that you could also just make it into an executable and throw it in your `$HOME/bin/`

Comment: Try using the bundle identifier instead of the app name- `alias chrome='open -b com.google.Chrome'`

Comment: What is the output of ``echo $SHELL``? If you're using bash, adding the alias to ``.profile`` or ``.bash_profile`` should work.

Comment: Add it to the files `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`. You're using the Apple version of bash, which sources the configuration files differently than GNU's bash releases. I can't remembe correctly but I think Apple's version only reads `~/.bashrc` at startup so you need bashrc to `source ~/.bash_profile` to source other files at startup.

Comment: @jahhein Terminal treats each tab/window as a login shell, Linux usually doesn’t. Bash reads different files if it runs as a login shell

Comment: $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash@ivicaa

Comment: `$ echo $PATH
/Users/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin` @njboot

Answer (score 1):

You need to relogin( to apply changes from .bashrc)
or do

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

which do the same work for your needs